# Is it safe to create a static file on asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, static, sitecore

I get an asp.net project (sitecore) where my client does not have a license to run the project on localhost. So I have to do development directly on the server / portal azure by app service editor

My client wants to add 2 new pages. so I do it like this

On the root of project, I make new folder. The name is static folder. Then I make the html file. The name is `test.html`

Then on the `Web.config`, I add like this :

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
       <add wildcard="*/Investor" destination="/static/test.html" />
    </httpRedirect>
  </system.webServer>
```

I try like that and it works

Is this way good and safe? or is there a better way? I have no other options

Answer (score 0):

The good and safe ways to do it are either (a) deploy to development environment, test, and promote upward to staging and then production, or (b) blue/green deployment. Editing directly on the production server is never a good idea.

Editing web.config, adding a folder to root, and making other changes to the site may seem seamless to you, but under the covers you may be triggering the application to recycle on the fly or recompile. If your application is stateful, this could cause users to be spontaneously logged out (best case) or experience strange and intermittent behavior (worst case).

I understand your client is playing it cheap here, so they need to understand that the practice they are forcing you to follow is neither good nor safe.

Comment: What do you mean `users to be spontaneously logged out`? For this case, I have no other options

Comment: It depends on your application. If it is stateful, and you store something in session state, it'll get lost when the application recycles. In some cases this can result in a logout, e.g. if user context is stored in session.

Comment: I don't have a login feature on the website. I only have the login feature in cms / admin

Comment: then for my case, what should I do? I'm just a freelance. I can't ask my client to buy the license